# Leave first row as empty and update the value from another column leaving the first row as empty/blank in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

Create a new column (Column 2) from column 1 with first row as empty or blank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p65PD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add 2 more columns:
Ranking:

```
Rank =
RANKX ( 'Table1', [Column1],, ASC )
```

and Column 2:

```
Previous =
LOOKUPVALUE ( Table1[Column1], Table1[Rank], 'Table1'[Rank] - 1 )
```

You will get the table:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Create a dummy table with a row that has 'null' as value.

Now union both the tables (Source and Dummy)

```
Table 3 = UNION('Table 2','Table') // Table -> Source and Table 2 -> Dummy
```

Create a **Rank** formula to add row number and sort the required column

```
IF('Table 3'[ID] = BLANK(), COUNT('Table 3'[ID]), RANKX('Table 3','Table 3'[ID],'Table 3'[ID],ASC)-1)
```

Here ID is source column of union table, This will add the row number and sort to bring the null record to bottom.

Now use below formula to add the source column as required. using formula from Andrew

```
LOOKUPVALUE ( 'Table 3'[ID], 'Table 3'[Rank], 'Table 3'[Rank] - 1 )
```

Add these 3 columns to the visual and change the font color for values and Column to white and reduce the column size to Minimum and rename column name to '.'

[image]